# Можно ли в TPanel разместить текст на 2-х строках?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в `TPanel` разместить текст на 2-х строках? Как?

Comment: Мне бы хотелось, чтобы вокруг текста была рамочка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальные символы перехода на следующую строку и возврата каретки: `#$D#$A`
Но свойства `Caption` таких компонентов, как `TLabel` их не понимает (будет рисовать только квадратики). Но компонент `TMemo` нормально с ними работает по определению.

Если вам нужна рамочка, то что вам мешает поставить панель, убрать у нее капшн, и вставить внутрь панели два лэйбла (Главное сделать родителем именно панель, а не форму, на которой лежит панель. А то лэйблы будут спрятаны под панелью)? Или использовать TMemo? Ну или совсем брутальный вариант - рисовать рамочку с помощью канвы.

Comment: Да, сделал, как вы советовали (но я сделал панель и один с WordWrap=True лейбл), теперь нормально. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

str="Первая,"_" вторая";

ну вот этот знак поставить, вроде как может получиться. ну или как там \n или /n для переноса.

я особо не помню, но вопрос то простой, там 2 ответа либо это реально сделать, либо нет. Попробовать намного быстрее чем задавать подобный вопрос :)

Comment: Нет, так не получается... Попробовал еще кинуть TLabel на TPanel, но текст TLabel не виден. Можно ли это исправить?